# Why would a select on a single table refer to another table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple select on a table, but the execution plan shows that another table is involved, in another database. This is definitely a table and not a view and I can't see database auditing turned on so what could cause this?

[image]

Comment: for future reference, when sharing an execution plan, it's far more helpful if you get the XML version and paste that into https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ then share the link in your question.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I actually just worked it out; there is a security policy in place which is causing this, strange though as not even profiler picked that up

Roger

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the policy do?

Comment: Is this because there's a synonym for the actual table?

Comment: The row level security policy was checking against a staff table to check that they had access to the staffskills table. I've now found out the reason why they have so much locking on this skills table and it seems the easy fix is change it to a memory optimised table